# Empty thread name in log when Spring Boot enables virtual threads

Tags: spring-boot

The log is as follows, the thread name is blank.

```
2024-03-22T10:42:31.114+08:00 DEBUG 3168 --- [               ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'text/plain;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] and supported [text/plain]
2024-03-22T10:42:31.115+08:00 DEBUG 3168 --- [               ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing ["Hello World!"]
2024-03-22T10:42:31.115+08:00 DEBUG 3168 --- [               ] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually set the name of the virtual thread in the thread factory:

```java
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
        
        return protocolHandler -> {
            protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(Thread.ofVirtual()
                            .name("coroutine-", 1).factory()));
        };
    }
}
```